# Loop AVPlayerItem in presented AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using `AVPlayerViewController` to show my videos in fullscreen mode. In my `BaseController` I have implemented `AVPlayerItem` and `AVPlayer`. I have added `self.playerItem.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None`
 and I am adding notification for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`. The problem is, that is in `BaseController` and not in `AVPlayerViewController`. Reading Apple documentation, there is strict NO for subclassing `AVPlayerViewController`.

> Important
>   Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

What is the best way to detect `AVPlayerViewController` `AVPlayerItem` that is finished so I can set `seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)`? I am able to use `AVPlayer` adding it as a subview and loop the video, but I want to be able to loop the video from `AVPlayerViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Try this man:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];}
```